# Retrieve the NAME of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, parameters, scope

I would like to retrieve the NAME of the variable (not its value), through my function. Here is my code, but it does not work. Why?

```js
myVariable = "123";

function myFunction (a) {
  varName = window[a]; // to get the NAME !, not the value...
  $('body').append(varName);
}

myFunction(myVariable);
// output : undefined
// output expected : "myVariable"
```

Comment: You can't really do this, at least not in this form. The name given to the function is not preserved, and is irrelevant to the function's execution.

Comment: Is calling it like `myFunction({ myVariable })` or `myFunction('myVariable'}` an option? In that case you get a key/value structure (Object) you can use, or a string you can call `window[a]` with.

Comment: @tadman : Yes !!!... It works like a charm. Many Thanks !. I make an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here : (Many Thanks to @tadman...)

```
myVariable = "123"; 

function myFunction (a) {   
    
    varName = a;
    varValue = window[a];
      
        $('body').append(varName); 
        $('body').append(varValue);
}

myFunction('myVariable');
// output : 123 myVariable
// parameter "stringify"...!!
```